# Compare 2 list of dictionnary based on selected key without for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

Assume I have this 2 list of dictionnary:

```
Dict1=[
    {"name": "James","age": "21"},
    {"name": "Evelyn","age": "28"},
    {"name": "William","age": "31"}
]

Dict2=[
    {"name": "James","age": "21","city":"NYC","Gender":"M"},
    {"name": "William","age": "25","city":"NYC","Gender":"M"},
    {"name": "Ella","age": "17","city":"NYC","Gender":"F"}
]
```

How can i compare them based on name key only and get the whole entry from dict2, in this case the result must be:

```
new_dict=[
    {"name": "James","age": "21","city":"NYC","Gender":"M"},
    {"name": "William","age": "25","city":"NYC","Gender":"F"},
]
```

I am looking for a method to make this comparison based on one or many selected key and without using for loop.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop? This is the simplest and most obvious way to achieve this.

Comment: What you want is impossible without looping or reorganizing the data

Comment: As said in at least one of the answers: you have *list of dicts*. You don't have two dicts but two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little convoluted but you can use pandas to avoid using a loop:

```
import pandas as pd
Dict1=[
    {"name": "James","age": "21"},
    {"name": "Evelyn","age": "28"},
    {"name": "William","age": "31"}
]

Dict2=[
    {"name": "James","age": "21","city":"NYC","Gender":"M"},
    {"name": "William","age": "25","city":"NYC","Gender":"M"},
    {"name": "Ella","age": "17","city":"NYC","Gender":"F"}
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(Dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Dict2)

df = df2[df2['name'].isin(df1['name'])]
print(df.to_dict(orient="records"))
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'James', 'age': '21', 'city': 'NYC', 'Gender': 'M'}, {'name': 'William', 'age': '25', 'city': 'NYC', 'Gender': 'M'}]
```

Comment: Worth highlighting that this achieves the aim of not using `for` in the code, but `pandas` will still be looping behind-the-scenes (if the aim is a more philosophical one to do with programming styles).

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is impossible without looping. You can eventually **hide** the looping by using a library or a complex way, but the simplest is to loop.

Now there is the **bad way** and the **good way** to loop. The bad one would be to check each element of Dict1 for each element of Dict2 (O(n*m) complexity).

Good one would be to construct a `set` index of the names in Dict1 and use them to match the names of Dict2:

```
names = set(d['name'] for d in Dict1)
new_dict = [d for d in Dict2 if d['name'] in names]
```

output:

```
>>> new_dict
[{'name': 'James', 'age': '21', 'city': 'NYC', 'Gender': 'M'},
 {'name': 'William', 'age': '25', 'city': 'NYC', 'Gender': 'M'}]
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway, this is a good solution too but my technical lead forbid me to use the for loop.

Comment: @Med then please come back with the answer when you have it. I am curious to see what the loop-less solution is. My guess, there will be a loop involved somewhere, but hidden ;)

Comment: sure, i'll keep you in touch

Comment: finally i convince him that it is difficult to resolve this case without the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Med ;) so what was your instructor's solution?

Comment: You welcome @mozway. He didn't suggest any solution and i think he rushed when he said to not use the for loop. Finally he allowed me to use it as I see fit.

Answer (score 2):

1. Just for clarity, you named your lists "Dicts". This may get confusing in the future.
2. Assuming that the names are unique, you could use dictionaries like so:

```
d1 = {person['name']: person for person in Dict1}
d2 = {person['name']: person for person in Dict2}
result = [person for name, person in d2.items() if name in d1]
# result is:
[
  {'name': 'James', 'age': '21', 'city': 'NYC', 'Gender': 'M'},
  {'name': 'William', 'age': '25', 'city': 'NYC', 'Gender': 'M'}
]
```

There are other ways to achieve that, some are even more efficient, but if you need readability, this may help.

Edit: This obviously uses loops, but what you request can not be done without iterating over the collections. So I assume that you just want to avoid a `for` block.